# What's outdated in this JavaCC project?

Tags: javacc

I have tried a simple JavaCC example project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50377/Create-Your-Own-Programming-Language).

However I get quite a few errors, I'm guessing that a few things have changed in 4 years. But I don't see any difference in a newly generated example file (just a MyVisitor class extending DepthFirstVoidVisitor but I've tried to include that aswell). Maybe a too big thing to ask, but can anyone help fixing this?

Comment: I think the question is a bit unfocussed.  I'd suggest you solve the problems you can.  For any individual problems, boil them down to a minimal example and ask about them individually.  You might try contacting the author directly.

Comment: As a more general comment:  Very little has changed to JavaCC that is not backward compatible.   As to JTB, I have no idea.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I'll try to fix it again.